# How are ionic buttons getting announced to the screen reader?

Tags: ionic-framework, accessibility

Currently whilst writing end to end tests with Cypress, using testing library, I noticed that some buttons in the app that were rendered via ionic's `ion-button` weren't findable under a button role.

Looking into the DOM I saw no `role="button"`, `tabindex="0"`, or anything else to indicate that this should be announced to the screen reader as such. In the accessibility inspector in Chrome the button also showed no name (although the button had text content).

I also couldn't see any elements being inserted into the DOM with `aria-live="polite"`, which is the default trick I know to force announce something to the screen reader.

All this to say, I'd have expected the button to not be announced to the screen reader as such, and yet, it was. Testing with orca the button was correctly announced as a push button, with its name as its text content.

So what's going on? How is Ionic achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button):

> The button component renders **a native button element** which allows it
> to take advantage of the functionality that a native button provides.

(emphasis mine)

...so, you should not expect to find `role=button` and `tabindex=0` anywhere. Those attributes are unnecessary. They are set automatically if you use a native button element. Automated accessibility checks will typically flag superfluous role and tabindex attributes with a warning, or even an error.

Furthermore, a native button element will respond correctly to ENTER/SPACE (generating a click event) when in focus, whereas if aria is used, you may have to consider listening for particular keypresses, and then generate a synthetic click event, or just call the click handler directly from the key event handler.

Regarding the name, a button, like most UI controls, **derives its accessible name from the text nodes inside it** (including the alt text associated with an `img` used as a a label). Otherwise the name may be taken from an appropriate aria attribute, such as `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby`.

So a native button (such as the one provided by the "guts" of `ion-button`) gives you a lot of accessibility "for free", whereas using the aria button role requires additional work.